# Custom widget on QItemDelegate editor for QTableView

Tags: python, layout, pyqt4, pyside, qitemdelegate

I have a `QTableView` showing a data from a custom model. I have a `QItemDelegate` for the edition on each of the cells. One column of the view has a custom widget comprised by a `QLineEdit` and a `QCheckBox`. When I click on the cells of this column the editor is shown and it works, but it doesn't fit the table cell. Moreover, when I enlarge a row and click on the cell, I can see the data of the cell behind the widget.

Is there a way that my widget behaves like a normal editing widget for a `QItemDelegate` on the view? i.e when created it uses all the vertical space of the cell?

This is my widget (simplified):

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(parent)
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(parent)
        self.checkBox.setChecked(False)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox, 0, 1)
```

My delegate (simplified):

```
class MyDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return MyWidget(parent)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        pass

    def setEditorData(self, editor, model, index):
        pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of different problems:

1. The vertical size-policy of a `QLineEdit` is fixed by default, so it will not expand to fill the availabe space.
2. The layout has a default contents margin (i.e. padding) which may constrain the size of the contained widgets.
3. By default, a `QWidget` does not draw its own background automatically, so the cell's data may be visible underneath.
4. If the widget takes up **all** the space in the cell, it will no longer be possible to show that the cell is selected.

All these problems can be fixed as follows:

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        # create an inner widget
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        # disable widget transparency
        widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        # allow the line-edit to fully expand
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(widget)
        self.lineEdit.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy(
            QtGui.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
            QtGui.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding))
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(widget)
        self.checkBox.setChecked(False)
        # trim space on right side of checkbox
        self.checkBox.setText('')
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(widget)
        # remove the inner margin
        hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        hbox.setSpacing(3)
        hbox.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        hbox.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        # set the selection rectangle width
        layout.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        layout.addWidget(widget)
```

And will look like this:

[image]